What is the intepretation of a Hessian with only negative and zero eigenvalues?
I'm looking at a high-dimensional optimisation problem. Specifically, one involving a function $F(c_n)$ which depends on N parameters (in my case $N=200$). I have been able to minimise this function numerically using gradient descent and now wish to characterise the nature of the critical point I have reached (saddle or minimum).
To do this, I calculated the Hessian and found that it had a zero determinant and two negative eigenvalues with the rest being zero (I've included a plot of the eigenvalues below for clarity. Not only this, but the spectrum seems to take this form at every point I look at. I understand this means that the critical point is degenerate, however, is there any further way I can characterise this point to understand it's nature better? Also is there a significance to the Hessian having such a similar spectrum at all points?
Hessian spectrum
